# Keycloak return 401 instead of 302 when token expire keyclaok

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak, httpresponse

When the token expires Keycloak normally return 302(redirect to logout) ; however , I want to return 401 instead of 302 in the api response .

I am using spring boot framework , here the keyloack configuration

```
@KeycloakConfiguration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(jsr250Enabled = true)
public class GlobalSecurityConfiguration extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public KeycloakClientRequestFactory keycloakClientRequestFactory;

    @Bean
    @Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    public KeycloakRestTemplate keycloakRestTemplate() {
        return new KeycloakRestTemplate(keycloakClientRequestFactory);
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .and()
                .cors()
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .headers()
                .frameOptions()
                .disable()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("test/login").permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider = keycloakAuthenticationProvider();
        keycloakAuthenticationProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(new SimpleAuthorityMapper());
        auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new NullAuthenticatedSessionStrategy();
    }

    //    Starting from Keycloak Spring Boot Adapter 7.0.0,
//    due to some issues, the automatic discovery of the Keycloak configuration
//    from the application.properties (or application.yml) file will not work.
//    To overcome this problem, we need to define a KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver bean explicitly in a @Configuration class.
    @Bean
    public KeycloakConfigResolver KeycloakConfigResolver() {
        return new KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver();
    }
}
```

but I can not reach in which place It sends 302 when token expire to change the response to 401

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, you could use the `exceptionHandling()` method:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/web/server/ServerHttpSecurity.html#exceptionHandling(org.springframework.security.config.Customizer)

> **exceptionHandling**
>
> public ServerHttpSecurity
> exceptionHandling​(Customizer<ServerHttpSecurity.ExceptionHandlingSpec>
> exceptionHandlingCustomizer)
>
> Configures exception handling (i.e. handles when authentication is
> requested). An example configuration can be found below:

```
  @Bean
  public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
      http
          // ...
          .exceptionHandling((exceptionHandling) ->
              exceptionHandling
                  // customize how to request for authentication
                  .authenticationEntryPoint(entryPoint)
          );
      return http.build();
  }
 
Parameters:
    exceptionHandlingCustomizer - the Customizer to provide more options for the ServerHttpSecurity.ExceptionHandlingSpec
Returns:
    the ServerHttpSecurity to customize
```

and according to this page, https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/10715

You could simply do:

```
 http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED));
```

However I think this will always return `401 UNAUTHORIZED` on any (Authentication Exceptions) and not specifically Token Expired.

---

If you look at the documentation further, you can implement a custom `ServerAuthenticationEntryPoint`

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/web/server/ServerAuthenticationEntryPoint.html

Example:

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class GatewayAuthenticationEntryPoint implements ServerAuthenticationEntryPoint {

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> commence(ServerWebExchange exchange, AuthenticationException e) {
         
       exchange.getResponse().getHeaders().setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
            // resolve response status
            if (ex instanceof AccessDeniedException) {
                exchange.getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
            } else exchange.getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
            // compose error response
            final ErrorResponse error = new ErrorResponse(ex, exchange.getRequest().getURI().getPath(),
                    exchange.getRequest().getMethod(), HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
            exchange.getResponse()
                    .writeWith(getEncoder().encode(Mono.just(error), exchange.getResponse().bufferFactory(),
                            ResolvableType.forInstance(error), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,
                            Hints.from(Hints.LOG_PREFIX_HINT, exchange.getLogPrefix())));
            return Mono.error(ex);

    }
}
```

Comment: Yes , I believe there is another way to do it using key cloak client apis